# Using a Vec<u8> to mock file Write

Tags: vector, rust, mocking

My function signature is:

```
fn write_header(source_pkey: PublicKey, target_pkey: PublicKey, nonce: Nonce,
    mut output: &mut Box<&mut dyn Write>) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
```

I'm trying to test it by using a `Vec<u8>` to mock a file:

```
#[test]
fn test_write_header() {
    let mut vec = Vec::<u8>::new();
    let mut out = Box::new(&mut vec);
    write_header(
        PublicKey([1u8; 32]),
        PublicKey([2u8; 32]),
        Nonce([3u8; 24]),
        &mut out
    ).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(out.len(), 104);
}
```

but I get the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/encrypt.rs:45:13
   |
45 |             &mut out
   |             ^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn std::io::Write`, found struct `Vec`
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut Box<&mut dyn std::io::Write>`
              found mutable reference `&mut Box<&mut Vec<u8>>
```

I am using `dyn std::io::Write` as I need this function to accept both `File` and `Stdout` in normal operation, as well as `Vec<u8>` for testing.

Am I doing this all wrong, or is it a matter of convincing the compiler that `Vec<u8>` has the `Write` trait?

---

Update:

The `Box` is because this code wouldn't compile without it, due to `Sized` issues.

```
/// Open the program's output file, or stdout if there is no input file.
/// Note: stdout on Windows only accepts utf8.
pub fn open_output(output: Option<String>) -> anyhow::Result<Box<dyn Write>> {
    if let Some(filename) = output {
        Ok(Box::new(File::open(&filename)
            .context(format!("unable to open '{filename}' for output"))?))
    } else {
        Ok(Box::new(stdout()))
    }
}
```

Is there a way to remove this `Box`?  (Apologies for a follow-on question.)

Comment: Is there any reason why the `output` parameter is of type `&mut Box<&mut dyn Write>` rather than just `&mut dyn Write`?

Comment: @FrancisGagné Probably not, I'm still learning...  I was having trouble with things not being `Sized`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @FrancisGagne comments, you can use directly `&mut dyn Write`, and then pass a `&mut vec`:

```rust
use anyhow; // 1.0.52
use std::io::Write;


fn write_header(
    source_pkey: (),
    target_pkey: (),
    nonce: (),
    mut output: &mut dyn Write,
) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    output.write(&[1])?;
    anyhow::Ok(())
}

#[test]
fn test_write_header() {
    let mut vec = Vec::<u8>::new();
    write_header(
        (),
        (),
        (),
        &mut vec
    ).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(vec.len(), 1);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2d08c186f7439c7301d87111e72e2dd6)

Also you can use `impl Write` as the input parameter. This is neat, since you actually can make your function work for anything that implements `Write` itself:

```rust
fn write_header(
    source_pkey: (),
    target_pkey: (),
    nonce: (),
    mut output: impl Write,
) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    output.write(&[1])?;
    anyhow::Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd5db9424d2f1a07a41ea5f81342c1ff)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  In your first code block, is the first `mut` in `mut output: &mut dyn Write` needed?  VSCode underlines it in orange and nothing bad happens when I remove it.

Comment: @you are right, the nut is not actually needed. Since the type itself is a &mut already ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to keep the `Box` at the top level, as `main()` does not know whether `output` is a `Stdout`, a `File` or something else.

I've changed `write_header`'s signature to:

```
fn write_header(source_pkey: PublicKey, target_pkey: PublicKey, nonce: Nonce,
    output: &mut dyn Write) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
```

at Fracis Gagné's suggestion, which fixes the original issue.